# Nearly covering the complement of a nowhere dense set

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure, dense-subspaces

Let $A\subseteq [0,1]$ be a *nowhere dense subset* of $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure $0$, and let $A'$ be its complement. I want to prove that, for any fixed small $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a sequence of disjoint open intervals $I_1,I_2,...,I_N$ such that $I_i\cap A=\emptyset$ for all $i$ and: $$\sum_{i=1}^N m(I_i)>1-\varepsilon$$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Ie. we can cover all but $\epsilon$ of $A'$ with finitely many intervals.

My intuition behind this is that "if there is some region of $[0,1]$ that we can't manage to cover with intervals, then it must be dense; but since $A'$ is *nowhere dense*, this can't happen. So we can always at cover any interval of $A'$ which is so far uncovered a little bit more". This intuition actually makes me think that this should be an if and only if statement, but for my purposes I do not need the other direction. But maybe this is simplistic...

This is not my primary area of maths so I don't really know where to begin with a proof, other than that I guess it should be by contradiction. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Ah I should have clarified but I mean intervals which don't intersect $A$.

Comment: Ie., taking the Cantor set as an example, you can let $I_1 = (1/3,2/3), I_2=(1/9,2/9),I_3=(7/9,8/9),I_4=(1/27,2/27)$ etc., and just keep doing this till you've covered $1-\varepsilon$ of the set...

Comment: Yes again I should've clarified a null nowhere dense set! Question is updated.

Comment: Let $B\subseteq[0,1]$ be a closed nowhere dense set with $m(B)\gt1-\varepsilon$ and let $A$ be a countable dense subset of $B$; so $A$ is a nowhere dense countable subset of $[0,1]$ whose closure has measure $\gt1-\varepsilon$, and an open subset of $[0,1]$ which is disjoint from $A$ will have measure $\lt\varepsilon$ To do what you want to do, you need $A$ to be a closed null set, like the Cantor set; then its complement will be the union of a sequence of disjoint open intervals whose measures add up to $1$.

Comment: Okay... So it would be true to say that this property holds of any set which is holomorphic to the Cantor set?

Comment: Oops I meant homomorphic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible for arbitrary nowhere dense $A$ as being nowhere dense doesn't imply that $A$ has zero Lebesgue measure (see [Fat Cantor sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set), for example).

Moreover, since the intervals have to be in the exterior, the sum of measures cannot exceed the measure of the exterior of $A$. So, if the exterior has measure $<1$, the statement doesn't hold:

Let $F$ be a fat Cantor set with positive measure obtained by removing intervals with rational end points. Let $A$ be the rationals in $F$ (i.e., the endpoints). Then $A$ is nowhere dense (being a subset of $F$) and has measure zero (being a subset of the rationals), but the closure of $A$ is $F$ and has positive measure. This means that you cannot get intervals in the exterior of $A$ whose sum of measures gets close to $1$ (the problem being that some of the mass is in the boundary of $A$).

Assuming $A$ is closed, this is possible by [inner regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_regular_measure) of the Lebesgue measure: given $\epsilon>0$, there's some compact set $K$ in $A'$ whose measure is at least $1-\epsilon$. Cover $K$ by intervals contained in $A'$ and take a finite subcover (and take unions et c. to make them disjoint) to get a finite collection of intervals in $A'$ whose union contains $K$.

(In the other direction, if $A$ is closed with measure zero, then it cannot contain any interval, hence is nowhere dense).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this makes sense!